# Django REST Framework API Key

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, django-views, postman

I'm trying to use Django REST Framework API Key package. I installed it and configure it correctly. I need to mack HTTP request to endpoint that has permissions of HasAPIKey. {I need to pass key to access it }

firstly I create API key in the admin page. Then I tried to access with that API. and I git this error. `"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."`

I think that I don't configure the api key correctly. I don't know how to do it :(
[image]

Comment: Can you show up us your REST_FRAMEWORK settings?

Comment: I don't add any settings  of REST_FRAMEWORK, I add ```permission_classes = [HasAPIKey,]  ``` in viewset